# Are Deep Neural Networks limited to grayscale images depending on whether you use Seq. or Func. API?

Tags: deep-learning, image

When I say DNN, I mean the simple usage of densely connected neurons (not CNN).

Say we are using Keras (with Tensorflow backend), the input_dim, using the Sequential API, can only take an integer or None value which restricts it to taking grayscale images right?

However since the functional API can accept dimensions that aren't just restricted to integers I would assume that it can take RGB images as opposed to only grayscale images?

If anyone can confirm or support, that would be great?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is no, they are not limited.

However, your statements seem to contain multiple misunderstandings, so let's first clarify them:

- The sequential and functional APIs in Keras are different approaches for structuring the layers of a neural network. Both can have dense layers and convolutional layers.
- Convolutional layers exploit information locality and therefore normally perform better on images, where information locality is key.
- Dense layers, on the other hand, can only handle vectors as input, therefore, anything we want to feed as input to a dense layer must be a vector; we can feed image data as input to a dense layer, but we must first remove the *spatial organization* (i.e. [flattening](https://keras.io/api/layers/reshaping_layers/flatten/)), that is, we must lose the information about which pixel is next to another, and which channel it is in.

With this information in mind, we can conclude that, while we can use images, either grayscale or color, as input to dense layers, we need to flatten the image as a vector, which makes dense layers in general not very appropriate to receive images as input, because the locality information is not used by them.

**Update**: regarding the ability for dense layers to accept inputs of more than one dimension, the multiplication takes place along the last dimension, as explained in the [documentation](https://keras.io/api/layers/core_layers/dense/):

> Note: If the input to the layer has a rank greater than 2, then `Dense` computes the dot product between the `inputs` and the `kernel` along the last axis of the `inputs` and axis 1 of the `kernel` (using `tf.tensordot`). For example, if `input` has dimensions `(batch_size, d0, d1)`, then we create a `kernel` with shape `(d1, units)`, and the `kernel` operates along axis 2 of the `input`, on every sub-tensor of shape `(1, 1, d1)` (there are `batch_size * d0` such sub-tensors). The output in this case will have shape `(batch_size, d0, units)`.

But this is applicable to both the functional and sequential APIs.

Comment: I agree with everything said here. Yes you cleared up a very important point i forgot to mention. But what is weird here is that if we create a dense layer using the Functional API, we can increase the input size beyond that of just an integer. So what does that imply for Densely connected layers now? (and i don't just mean batch size.. i.e. (None, vector_dim), i mean (None, None, vector_dim))

Comment: I updated the answer with the relevant information.